# In Python Getting KeyError while filtering the snapshots based on Tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I need to skip the snapshots whichever is having particular tag and get the Snapshot ID's of rest of them. I wrote the below code to do the same but its throwing "Keyerror: 'Tags'"

I have included both code and raw data where we can see the Tags, Description, accountID and so on. As you can see in the raw data, there is a Key with 'Tags'. I am not sure why I am still getting this KeyError.

Please let me know what is the mistake I am doing here

```
            import boto3
            import json
            import sys
            from pprint import pprint

            def filter_the_given_tag():           
              ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2')
              ec2_desc = ec2Client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['*********'])
              
              for instance_snap in ec2_desc['Snapshots']:
                if ('ipsm_des_SR1' in d.get('Key') for d in instance_snap['Tags']):
                  continue
                elif ('ipsm_des_SR2' in d.get('Key') for d in instance_snap['Tags']):
                  continue
                else:
                  snapshots =[''];
                  snapshots.append(instance_snap.get('SnapshotId'))
                  print (snapshots)

            def lambda_handler(event, context):
                return filter_the_given_tag()
                
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                lambda_handler(None, None)
```

Raw data - {'Description': 'Created for test', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '******', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': 'snap-456789', 'VolumeSize': 30, 'Tags': [{Key': 'app:L1:L1', 'Value': 'true'}, {'Key': 'app:name', 'Value': '123421'}, {'Key': 'hsm:test', 'Value': 'flexi'}]}

Comment: Looks like you've got a typo in line 7. 'secrestsmanager' should be 'secretsmanager'
With this change, I then get a "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials" but I see no KeyError.

Comment: @Gary02127 I have modified the code again. Please Try now. That ' secretsmanager' -- I configure and manage internally thats why throwed error I guess

Answer (score 1):

The code keeps changing and throwing different errors. I don't see the KeyError you mention. So, here's an easy fix for the alleged `KeyError` only.

Change:

```
          for instance_snap in ec2_desc['Snapshots']:
```

to:

```
          for instance_snap in ec2_desc['Snapshots']:
              if instance_snap.get('Tags') == None:
                  continue
```

If you are actually seeing a KeyError, this should make it go away.
If you want more help, you need to post code that generates the error you claim to see.

Bigger pic, try something like this:

```
for instance_snap in ec2_desc['Snapshots']:
    if instance_snap.get('Tags') == None:
        continue
    if ('ipsm_des_SR1' in d.get('Key') for d in instance_snap['Tags']):
        continue
    if ('ipsm_des_SR2' in d.get('Key') for d in instance_snap['Tags']):
        continue
    snapshots = ['']
    snapshots.append(instance_snap.get('SnapshotId'))
    print (snapshots)
```

Comment: Last edited one is the complete code where I am getting the 'KeyError' in this line --"if ('ipsm_des_SR1' in d.get('Key') for d in instance_snap['Tags']): ". Let me try with this suggested answer.

Comment: Tried this code you have given, it is not skipping the tag given in condition. I am getting the Snapshot IDs with 'ipsm_des_SR1' tag as well which should be skipped.

Comment: You need to add the extra if-statement I've added and keep yours as well.

Comment: I extended the code sample to give you a better idea. Note that there's no need for the elif tree. Simple if statements will do because of the nature of the continue statement